# Any advice to fix "Compilation error. Script could not be translated from: |B|for i = 0 to "

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, back-testing

I'm new to coding and wrote a script to test how many times the breakout of highs and lows that were created in the Asia Session happened during the London Session. However, it does not seem to work, it gives me a "Compilation error. Script could not be translated from: |B|for i = 0"
Any advice or tips would be appreciated. cheers.

Here is the script:

```
// This pine script studies the last 365 days worth of data and uses the `timeframe.isintraday` and 
// `timeframe.period` functions to identify the current timeframe and session. Time ranges are defined 
// for the Asia, London, and New York sessions and the `highest` and `lowest` functions are used to 
// identify the high and low from each session. The `barssince` function is used to determine if and 
// when those highs and lows were broken in the London session.

study("Last 365 Days - High/Low Breakouts")

// Define time ranges for each session
asiaSession = time >= time("19:00") and time <= time("00:00")
londonSession = time >= time("02:00") and time <= time("05:00")
newYorkSession = time >= time("07:00") and time <= time("10:00")

// Use `timeframe.isintraday` and `timeframe.period` to identify the current session
asiaSessionActive = timeframe.isintraday and asiaSession
londonSessionActive = timeframe.isintraday and londonSession
newYorkSessionActive = timeframe.isintraday and newYorkSession

// Initialize variables for counting breakouts
asiaHighBreakout = 0
asiaLowBreakout = 0
highBrokenFirst = 0
lowBrokenFirst = 0

// Loop through the last 365 days worth of data
for i = 0 to 364
    date = timenow - i
    // Get the high and low for the Asia session
    asiaHigh = highest(high, date, asiaSession)
    asiaLow = lowest(low, date, asiaSession)

    // Check if the Asia high was broken in the London session
    if barssince(high > asiaHigh) > 0
        asiaHighBreakout := asiaHighBreakout + 1
    // Check if the Asia low was broken in the London session
    if barssince(low < asiaLow) > 0
        asiaLowBreakout := asiaLowBreakout + 1

    // Check if the Asia high was broken first, followed by the Asia low
    if asiaHighBreakout > 0 and asiaLowBreakout == 0
        // Count the breakout
        highBrokenFirst := highBrokenFirst + 1
    // Check if the Asia low was broken first, followed by the Asia high
    if asiaLowBreakout > 0 and asiaHighBreakout == 0
        // Count the breakout
        lowBrokenFirst := lowBrokenFirst + 1

// Create a box to display the results
box_set(
    text = "High Broken First: " + tostring(highBrokenFirst) + "\n" +
           "Low Broken First: " + tostring(lowBrokenFirst),
    color = color.white,
    location = location.bottom_left,
    title = "Breakout Results"
)
```

main changes I made were:

Using the timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.period functions to determine the current session, rather than using time ranges.
Using the barssince function with the high and `low

Comment: What is `box_set()`?

Comment: There are WAY too many errors with this code. You don't state the version number (and you need to in this case), you're using too many arguments in the `highest` and `lowest` functions, you are using those functions in an `if` block, you are calling the function `box_set` which doesn't exist etc. On top of this, you are using built in variables wrong. For example - `timenow` returns the UNIX time in milliseconds, so subtracting 364 from that will give you the time 364 milliseconds ago and not 364 days ago... It's either an AI code, or you really need to start this thing all over again

Comment: It looks like you are missing the version declaration. Add `//@version=4` to the top of you code.